# what does "Nothing like the easy stuff" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

This sentence is in the movie, fast and furious 5 the Rio heist. And this is the subtitle.

**Roman**: How are we supposed to get Reyes' handprint?

**Dominic**: Han.

**Dominic**: You're up.

**Han**: Sure. Nothing like the easy stuff.

**Gisele**: Let's go. I'll drive.

Comment: "The movie"  Please edit to say which movie.  There is more than one movie in English.

Comment: And speaker names are more useful than timing codes.

Answer (score 2):

"(There is) nothing like X" means that X is special and good.

> There's nothing like cup of tea in the morning

So literally "The easy stuff is great". or "Thank you for giving me the easy task to do". But this should be understood in context. I suspect that "Getting Reyes handprint" is going to be difficult. So calling this "the easy stuff" is ironic. So we understand this to be the character complaining about having the hardest task.